# What are the left and right cosets of $A_n$ in $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, visualization

> What are the left and right cosets of $A_n$ in $S_n$?

I know that $A_n$ is the set of all even permutations and $S_n$ is the set of all permutations.

I was looking online and found that since $A_n$ is normal, the other coset is $S_n - A_n$(since cosets partition a group).

For $A_4$ in $S_4$, it's pretty visual because you can clearly see $e$ and $(1,2)$ are the left cosets and $e$ is the right coset.

> Is there any way to visually see it for $A_n$ in $S_n$ by listing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $e$ and $(1,2)$ are _representatives_ of   cosets, and since $A_n$ is a normal subgroup, the right and left cosets are the same

Comment: What do you mean by "visually see"?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Since $A_n$ is normal in $S_n$, we have for all $\sigma\in S_n$ that $\sigma A_n\sigma^{-1}=A_n$; hence $\sigma A_n=A_n\sigma$; that is, the left and right cosets are the same.

---

Also, here $e$ and $(1,2)$ are not cosets; they are *representatives* of cosets. The cosets look like this:

$$\sigma A_n=\{\sigma\tau\mid \tau\in A_n\}$$

for each $\sigma\in S_n$ up to the representative.

---

To see $A_n$ in $S_n$ visually, try reading [*"Visual Group Theory,"*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/088385757X/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awdb_t1_EuAWDbHB8GVWS) by Carter.